# The Date format in iOS is not clear...

Tags: ios, date

```
  NSString* lastModified  =   @"26 Jun 2015 11:16";
  activityTime           =   [dateObject getDateFromString:lastModified andFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" toFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
```

What's wrong with the format that I have used? I always get the activityTime variable as nil.

I have checked apple documentation also... Same format has given for my usecase. But it is not working though.

Need some insights on this!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The formats looks ok for me. Is the ```getDateFromString:andFormat:toFormat:``` comes from the iOS API. I do not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str =  @"26 Jun 2015 11:16"; /// here this is your date with format yyyy-MM-dd

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"]; //// here set format of date which is in your output date (means above str with format)

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str]; // here you can fetch date from string with define format

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];// here set format which you want...

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; //here convert date in NSString
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Comment: You can add above code in that method also and pass both params